# Python 2.6 Cassandra 2.0.1 ReadTimeout

Tags: python, cassandra

I need to read all of the rows in a table (over a million). I've already read about pagination (http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/datastax-python-driver-2-0-released) - didn't help much.
The code is pretty straight forward:

```
...
retry = RetryPolicy()
retry.RETRY = 10
cluster = Cluster(
[ ... ],
reconnection_policy=ConstantReconnectionPolicy(5.0, 100),
auth_provider=auth_provider,
load_balancing_policy=RoundRobinPolicy(),
default_retry_policy=retry,
port=9042)
session = cluster.connect("test")
session.default_timeout = 9999
session.default_fetch_size = 1000

...
...

uname_stmt = SimpleStatement(q, fetch_size=100)
uname_stmt.consistency_level = ConsistencyLevel.ONE

for row in session.execute(uname_stmt):
  ...
```

Basically after about 5 min or so (can be 1 min or it can be 10) the last for loop triggers this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 67, in <module>
for row in session.execute(uname_stmt):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 2939, in next
result = self.response_future.result(self.timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 2771, in result
raise self._final_exception
cassandra.ReadTimeout: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'data_retrieved': False, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 1}
```

Any help would be awesome!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That may be because of cassandra is trying to reorganise all the SSTables.

That is why readout operation is happening on many SSTables and getting timed out.

Cassandra manages the accumulation of SSTables on disk using compaction.

Try using compact command may help.

**nodetool compact**

Comment: Thanks for reply, I've tried it, didn't help :( 
I've also installed the latest Cassandra - same problem.